# "Scattered" gallery

Tags: css, attachments, gallery

I'm building a theme for a portfolio-type site. I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

This site uses some kind of Foundation Grid CSS to size the thumbnails using different sizes. My question is, which method would you use to set a CSS class for every thumbnail? I'm thinking of using the `attachment_fields_to_edit` filter to add a CSS class field to every attachment, but I don't know if there's a better way to approach this.

```
function attachment_fields_to_edit( $form_fields, $post ) {
    $parent = $post->post_parent;
    if ( 'portfolio' == get_post_type( $parent ) ) {
        $form_fields['attachment-css-class'] = array(
            'label' => __( 'CSS class' ),
            'input' => 'text',
            'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_attachment-css-class', true )
        );
    }
    return $form_fields;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Rather than set individual CSS classes (which could cause layout issues depending on how many archives a thumbnail could appear on), you might fare better using CSS :nth-child pseudo-classes. Build your grid within your theme and use :nth-child odd, even, or specific numbers to identify which ones are smaller, which are larger.

Comment: But building the grid statically in the theme doesn't allow the user to modify gallery layouts easily. Am I wrong?

Comment: That's correct, but if you attach individual CSS classes they have no control over layouts either. You could create a few different layout options, set each one up as a shortcode, and still style with :nth-child so the styling is independent of the particular images chosen.

Comment: Please don't post to external website, instead add images to your post of what you're looking for. Asking users to go to an unfamiliar site that may not be around as long as this question will be ( or may become hijacked eventually ) it not an acceptable practice You may use the [`edit` link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/299723/edit) above to add in images or additional descriptions.